# RxJS - Processing HTTPrequests in sequence

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm currently trying to process HTTP Post requests in sequence,
additionally trying to repeat each failed request until it succeeds
(that is a requirement) and then and only then to continue with processing other requests.
My code looks like this for now (it not working as it should, retryWhen is not used properly, I am aware of that, it's used just as a starting point reference):

```
...
subject
  .pipe(
    concatMap(async request => await this._sendPostRequest(request)),
    retryWhen(errors =>
      errors.pipe(
        tap(error => this._logger.error('error sending request', error)),
        delayWhen(() => timer(5000))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe();
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!

Just attach your retry to the promise rather than the concatenated stream as a whole.

```ts
subject.pipe(     
  concatMap(request => defer(() => sendPostRequest(request)).pipe(           
    retryWhen(error$ => error$.pipe(               
      tap((error) => console.warn('error sending request', error)),               
      delay(1000)             
    ))         
  ))
).subscribe();
```

Comment: I have tried to implement the proposed solution but still doesn't work. Please check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/q9mdbl-snotik?devtoolsheight=50 idea is to use click event as request maker, after some time you can press any key to change the control value for deciding should we reject or resolve the httpRequest simulation... I am just seeing retrying indefinitely whatever I do ( my function simulateHttpRequest is not called again). Could you please check this example?

Comment: @MilosJocic Ah, Right. I don't use promises much and forgot that the different eager/lazy evaluation semantics play a role here. If you want to create a new promise on every re-try you can do so with `defer`. I've updated my answer, try that out and see if it does what you expect.

Comment: It's working. Thank you very, very much @mrk-sef.

If anyone is interested here is an updated example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/q9mdbl-xe5ugj?devtoolsheight=50